# Display one column from table in has many relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, has-many

I have has many relationship in my project between properties and videos. I am trying to display title from properties table where that title belongs to corresponding video in videos table.

```
properties (id, title)

videos (id, model_id, filename_video)
```

Here model_id is foreign key that points to properties table. With current code I get all titles displayed. Any help is appreciated. Here is my code.

Property.php

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Property extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function videos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Video::class, 'model_id');
    }
}
```

Video.php

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Video extends Model
{
    protected $guarded=['id'];

    public function properties()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Property::class);
    }

}
```

PropertyController.php

```
public function viewVideos(Property $property, Video $video)
{
    $results = DB::table('properties')
       ->join('videos', 'properties.id', '=', 'videos.model_id')
       ->select('properties.title')
       ->get();

    $video = $property->videos;

    return view('property.videos', compact('video', 'results'));
}
```

videos.blade.php

```
<h1 class="font-weight-light text-center text-lg-left mt-4 mb-0">
    Videos for 
    @foreach($results as $result)
        {{$result->title}}
    @endforeach
</h1>
```

Comment: exactly what are you displaying? video list with property title or property list?

Comment: @Karan I have that page videos where all videos for that property are listed. And I am trying on top of the page to show title of that property. Example, videos for 'title of that property'. '

Comment: what you are getting output of result query?

Comment: @Karan  Collection {#297 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => {#307 ▼
      +"title": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
    }
    1 => {#304 ▼
      +"title": "this is title for project one!!!"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: @Karan Or simply put, titles from different properties. And I need specific one title. In this case 'this title for project one!!! '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to setup like this:

**Property.php**

```
class Property extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function video()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Video::class);
    }
}
```

**Video.php**

```
class Video extends Model
{
    protected $guarded=['id'];

    public function properties()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Property::class, 'model_id');
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
$results = Property::with('videos')->where('title', $property->title)->get();
```

Comment: I get  Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'videos.property_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `videos` where `videos`.`property_id` = 22 and `videos`.`property_id` is not null)

Comment: Your `property` should have one video. Check answer again I updated it

Comment: I get titles from different properties, and I need just one title for that specific property

Comment: Wait in your query you have all of your data because you have `->get()` if you want one title specify which one with `->find()` of `->first()`

Comment: When I use first() it gets me one and same result for all properties. I need title that belongs to that property

Comment: Wait you got that title in your request or some variable? If you got why u just don't use in where? `->where('properties.title', $variable)` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196366/discussion-between-mare96-and-marko).

Answer (score -1):

You should try this:

```
$results = DB::table('properties')
       ->join('videos', 'properties.id', '=', 'videos.model_id')
       ->pluck('title');
```

Comment: I get Trying to get property 'title' of non-object error